# Count only fields with text/data, not formulas

Tags: excel, count

I have a listing of headcount within a given month that I am comparing to budgeted headcount. 
I have used  a vlookup to match budget to actuals.
Then: =IF(ISNA(M66),K66," ") to return names that are not in budget, but in actuals (HR file) or else blank.

Now I would like to count the names returned in the column , but I'm having trouble with the count functions recognizing the formula in the cells even though they are blank.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: remove the space from between the quotes of `=IF(ISNA(M66),K66," ")` then use `=COUNTIF(A1:A5,"<>""")` to count

Comment: Agree with you about removing space, Scott.....but I think your formula will still count "" values - see my suggestions

Comment: Thanks! Removing the space worked and: =COUNTIF(L4:L94,"?*") I appreciate your time and suggestions! Also thanks for numeric values suggestion.

Comment: @barryhoudini you are right, I did not test the formula, which is why I didn't suggest it as an answer

Answer (score 34, accepted):

[Edit - didn't notice the space in " " - remove that as Scott suggests then try below]

If range of data is A2:A100 try this formula to count text values but not ""

`=COUNTIF(A2:A100,"?*")`

or if you want to include numeric values too

`=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A100<>"")+0)`

Comment: Could you explain why that works? I don't understand what "?*" does

Comment: ? and * are wildcards - ? stands for any single character and * for any number of characters (including zero characters), so using "?*" (or "*?") will give you a count of any cell where a single character is followed (or preceded) by any other number of characters.....so that works to count **any** text string except a "zero length" one, but doesn't count numbers because wildcards don't work with numbers in this scenario

Comment: I see.  I had no idea wildcards could be used in Excel. Thank you!

Comment: What does '+0' work for the SUMPRODUCT scenario?

Answer (score 1):

```
COUNTA(A2:A100,"")-COUNTA(A2:A100)
```

Comment: Technically, this may be a complete answer but it always help the original poster (of the question) if you give a brief explanation as to why your answer works.  Remember we are here to learn.  Even long after the question has been answered.